# Unable to Set value in Date picker for Android app

Tags: android, datepicker

Below is the code written for Date Picker to set value

```
 List<WebElement> datePickerBox = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*
    [@class='android.widget.EditText']"));

    WebElement day = datePickerBox.get(0);
    WebElement month = datePickerBox.get(1);
    WebElement year = datePickerBox.get(2);

    day.sendKeys("05");
    System.out.println("xx : " + day.getText());
    System.out.println("xx : " + month.getText());
    System.out.println("xx : " + year.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

First time seeing this type of method to use date picker. So I can't help you to fix it, but I can offer method which I'm using for date picker (**for mobile applications**):

In your activity define these methods and these listeners:

```
    EditText dateE = findViewById(R.id.date_edit_text);
    // listener which will not open(close) the keyboard when field has focus
    // so on click will be opened just datepicker dialog.
    dateE.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus)
                showDialog(999);
            keyboardCloseListener.closeKeyboard(view);
            dateE.clearFocus();
        }
    });
    // (optional) on click open datepicker dialog
    dateE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showDialog(999);
        }
    });
```

Then in the same activity create initialize date set listener:

```
    // the listener defines what to do after date is selected.
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int year, int month, int day) {
            // after date select setting date to edit text as text.
            dateE.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append(month+1).append("-").append(day));
        }
    };
```

Finally method which creates dialog on edit text click:

```
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        if (id == 999) {
            int year = 1990;
            int month = 1;
            int day = 1;
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    myDateListener, year, month, day);
        }
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                myDateListener, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
```

Hope it helps you somehow...

Comment: Hi Sir, Thanks for your reply but, this seem to be a Code for Android developer. I'm trying to automate an Android app where Date need to set has per the value send via. using SendKeys in selenium

Comment: Hello, I understand you now. I'm offering you to fill your question with this information.